# Jquery side navigation animation

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, navigation

I'm trying to add a side navigation bar to my website, which animates in from the right hand side when the user has scrolled so that the normal navigation bar isnt visible. Ive managed to get it so its animating how I want but not when i want. It just alternates between being shown, and not being shown whenever the user scrolls, not whenever the user scrolls past the header.

I am using jquery and here is a jsfiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/2twmcmzh/1/ and my current js:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var $header = $('header');
    var $sideButtons = $('.roundSideButton');
    var scrollstate = 'hidden';
    var animating = false;
    var duration = 500;
    $( window ).scroll(function() {
        var scrollToTop = $(window).scrollTop(); 
        if(animating === false){
            if(scrollToTop > $('header').height() && scrollstate == 'hidden'){
                showSideButtons(true);
            }else if (scrollstate == 'shown' ){
                showSideButtons(false); 
            }
        }
    });


    function showSideButtons(hide){
        animating = true;
        if(hide){
            $.each($sideButtons,function(i) {
                $(this).stop().delay(i * (duration / 2)).animate({right:"20px"}, duration,function(){animating = false;});
            });
            setTimeout(function() {
                animating = false;
                scrollstate = 'shown';
                console.log(" " + scrollstate + " " + animating);
            }, duration * $sideButtons.length);
        }else{
            $.each($sideButtons,function(i) {
                $(this).stop().delay(i * (duration / 2)).animate({right:"-20px"}, duration);
            });
            setTimeout(function() {
                animating = false;
                scrollstate = 'hidden';
                console.log(" " + scrollstate + " " + animating);
            }, duration * $sideButtons.length);
        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand you correct, everything OK when the user scroll down. Whenever that the header is hidden the points are shown. (From I see in the fiddle). The problem start when the user scroll to the top, than the point are hidden before the header is shown. Right?

If so, you just need to copy the check like you did when the state is `hidden`.

```
if(animating === false){
        if(scrollToTop > $('header').height() && scrollstate == 'hidden'){
            showSideButtons(true);
        // I was added this check `scrollToTop < $('header').height()`
        } else if (scrollstate == 'shown' && scrollToTop < $('header').height()){
            showSideButtons(false); 
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thank you! I cant believe the answer was so simple :-/

Comment: Sometime you need an extra eyes to see the solutions. ;) It's happening to me a lot.. Good luck..